# Best table structure for *set* of ManyToMany

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, hash

I have 2 Java Entities - Students and Courses.
The relation between them is ManyToMany - each student has a lot of courses and each course can be taken by a lot of students.

Because there are a lot of repeated sets of courses, we decided to make a table of sets of courses, and every time a student wants to take a set of courses, he needs to look if there is already set like this, if there is, he'll use its id, and if not, he'll create this set. And if the student is done with this set, we'll set `null` in the setId field.

The problem is that the course table is dynamic - we can add and remove course any time (unless there is a student that uses this course), and there is no limit to the number of the courses - it can be even 150.

We need the search for the existence of a set, to be as quick as possible.

We thought about:

1. HashCode but this HashCode needs to be dynamic and it should support even 2^100 possibilities.
2. Concatenate the id's of the courses as a string and search that string to see if this set exists.
3. Assign for each course a prime number and the id of the set will the multiplication of the prime numbers - the problem with that is the biggest number (set of all the courses) can be too big, and the decomposition of the number can take a long time.

What can be the best implementation for that requirements? Any idea will be welcome!

(The reason that we don't want to use the traditional ManyToMany table is that a performance issue. There is a big calculation that causes this.)

Thanks!

Comment: What is HashCode?

Comment: What is set ?, Is it table or memory variable? and if it is table then how it can be set to null...?

Comment: @POrekhov HashCode is function that gives a unique number for each set - i.e if you give this function course number 1, 7, 15 it will give you a unique number X that it will not give you for any other set

Comment: @SunilKanjar a set is a multiple course for example set of courses can be course number [1, 15, 19, 24, 33] - if 2 students use the same set of courses I want them to have the same set-id

Comment: @J.Doe are you sure your hashcode function is unique?

Comment: @POrekhov usually you're right. It's not unique but very close to that. I need my HashCode to give a unique result.

Answer (score 1):

A prediction...

100 courses will lead to a few dozen very popular "sets", plus tens of thousands of infrequent sets.

You will find that the number of "sets" will be too unwieldy to be practical.

Answer (score 0):

I have face same problem in my project where I shows document listing with default columns and order and which came from one table and if user changes the order or make any field available in his listing then another entry make to that table and row id is set for current user.
Here in my case order was needful you can ignore that and store JSON for user Selected course list and if list already exist in table then in this case you can assign set id for that user.

- HashCode will not unique.
- Some time Concatenate will have blanks spacing issue so `SortedSet<Integer>` JSON is always same.
- For example: `SortedSet setA = new TreeSet();`